# Pyspark - using multiple crossJoins without crashing

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've been working on merging multiple but selected columns into a new dataframe using crossJoins. Each of those columns holds more than a million records.
whenever I join more than 5 columns Pyspark crashes. so by a solution suggested in another post got the issue solve doing crossjoins within 5 columns at maximum creating multiple dataframes that I eventually will have to crossjoins together, is there a way of creating a dataframe let say with 25 columns let say same length I mentioned before without crashing spark?

```
result1 = table.select("column1")\
.crossJoin(table.select("column2"))\
.crossJoin(table.select("column3"))\
.crossJoin(table.select("column4"))\
.crossJoin(table.select("column5"))\
.crossJoin(table.select("column6"))

result2 = table.select("column7")\
.crossJoin(table.select("column8"))\
.crossJoin(table.select("column9"))

result3 = table.select("column10")\
.crossJoin(table.select("column11"))\
.crossJoin(table.select("column12"))\
.crossJoin(table.select("column13"))\
.crossJoin(table.select("column14"))\
.crossJoin(table.select("column15"))
```

instead of doing all the crossjoins together.

Comment: cartesian product or do you have a where condition between tables/dataframes? pls show query.

Comment: in this case I'm using specific columns to create a new table that I will be adding to another table with same length. (as it comes from the exact table, reducing it to a more relevant table with specific identifiers and values needed).

Comment: so it is an inner join

Comment: No, is a crossJoin, kind of like what you will do using Pandas.concat() function. the problem comes when I have to join multiple columns in order for me to not crash the join I can only add 4 to 5 columns max. So, I did multiple subsets, but my wonder comes as I keep advancing I will need to eventually cross join all those subsets wish may cause the same initial issue I'm referring to the initial post

Comment: Best to show code and example, too vague.

Comment: I added the piece of code you were referring to. again If I do all those crossJoins together  , it just crashes (not ale to handle it.  although eventually I'll have to do a crossjoin over result1 + result2 +result3 hopefully this help you understand my inquiry here

Comment: Help is a big word, i have a few clues if you look at my postings. I will look.

Comment: It is a sizing issue of cartesian products, you do mot have enuff resourcs.

Comment: you mean is a memory issue? that is interesting that you point that out. I'm using sagemaker, and started with 5GB of memory and ended up increasing it to a 10GB and specifically with those cross joins I come across with this problem.